# How to programmatically communicate with a software device driver in Java or C#?

Tags: c#, java, usb, device-driver, hyperterminal

Recently I've installed a software device driver for a device that connects to my local machine via USB. How do I communicate with the device? Do I communicate directly with the installed software device driver?

Tools:

- OneTouch Ultra 2 glucometer
- Windows XP
- Meter Drivers for OneTouch(R) Software v1.12.0.0
- Custom Communication Protocols

Comment: What kind of device? On what kind of operation system? What API does the driver provide?

Comment: The protocol does not matter in the first place. The _transport_ matters. In the simplest case the driver just installs a virtual serial COM port. This can be opened like any other serial device with Java. THEN the protocol can be implemented in Java. <br> But with so little information about the specific device, driver and available APIs you will NOT get any usefull information.

Comment: The writers of the device driver usually define how to communicate with it.

Comment: it suggests using `HyperTerminal` to shell out commands...not sure if i like that approach...looking to potentially either Java wrap that, or write my own java `HyperTerminal`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The company offers both a "meter driver" and "communication protocols".  If you're wanting to write your own software to communicate with the meter, I'd fill out the form on http://www.onetouch.com/software_kit and see what that has to offer.

Comment: so you don't use the meter driver and communication protocols in conjunction?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use JNI to access the underlying OS. Standard Java provides no hooks into the OS at that level in pure Java.